# Java Exception in thread '"AWT-EventQueue-0"' java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

I've got a class called `Info` and it's method `load` contains this piece code:

```
Circuito[] circuito=new Circuito[19];
for(int i=0;i<circuito.length;i++)
   circuito[i] = new Circuito(nome,immPath,sfondoPath,previsioni,giri,tempoGiro,carico);
```

I pass correctly all the parameters (I printed the toString() method to check if it works).
Then, in another class called `New` I have this code:

```
Info info=new Info();
info.load();
System.out.println(info.getCircuito()[0].toString());
```

(The class `Info` contains the method `getCircuito` to returns the entire array).

then, I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at New.<init>(New.java:21)
```

the line 21 is the `System.out.print` line.

I don't understand which is the problem...Thank you for your help!

Comment: Show the code for `getCircuito()` method also.

Comment: Can't help without getCircuito method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only 3 possibilities for an NPE in the line

```
System.out.println(info.getCircuito()[0].toString());
```

are:

- info is `null`. Not possible because you successfully call `info.load()` before.
- `getCircuito()` returns `null`.
- `getCircuito()[0]` is `null`.

That's it. So in your case with the code for `load()` shown it probably is the `getCircuito()` returning `null`.

Edit: Found the reason. You are calling

```
Circuito[] circuito=new Circuito[19];
```

in your `load()` method. Therefore you are assigning your new array not to the class variable but to a new variable in a local scope which is gone again after the `load()` method. Change said line to

```
circuito=new Circuito[19];
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you are not filling your array due to some reason. May be you have defined the `Circuito` class instance of  `Info` class inside a very narrow scope, something like a loop.

Try calling to another index inside your Info class. If that works, then the issue is with index 0.

Try getting the whole array and printing it. I guess the whole array will be NULL.

Finally, check whether you have used static keyword in unnecessary place.